# I cant get my Images to detect the anchor and open into a new page

Tags: css, html

I have a school assignment that I need a 3x3 group of pictures that are all 200x200 and linked to a larger 800x800 picture of itself.

I have been grinding at this thing for 3 solid days and I just don't understand what I am doing wrong....PLEASE HELP

Maybe I am overthinking this assignment and adding the 9 pages for nothing and I am missing an easier way of doing this?

PLEASE HELP!!!

My thought process:

.css for formatting of my containers, borders, "placeholders"

9 seperate relative links within the "webiste" that will open into a new tab

the 9 200x200 pictures are the relative links to the other 9 pages

My Problem:

NONE of my href="Page 1-9.html" target="_blank" are working AT ALL

my code for the pages 1-9 follows

```
<html>
<body>
        <img src="images/America.jpg" alt="Is" style="width:800px;height:800px;">
</body>
```

```css
    #container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 640px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-image: url("images/Star.jpg");
}


#sectionOne{
 margin-right: 10px; 
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 display: block;
 

}


#sectionTwo{
 margin-right: 10px;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
 display: block;
}


#sectionThree{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left; 
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
}

#sectionFour{
 margin-right: 10px; 
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
 display: block;
}


#sectionFive{
 margin-right: 10px;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
 display: block;
}


#sectionSix{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left; 
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
}
#sectionSeven{
 margin-right: 10px; 
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
 display: block;
}


#sectionEight{
 margin-right: 10px;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
 display: block;
}


#sectionNine{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left; 
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
}

#header{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 height: 100px; 
 width: 700px; 
 background-image: transparent;
 border: transparent;
}


#footer{
 clear: left;
 height: 50px;
 width: 630px; 
 background-color: transparent;
 border: transparent;
}

.boarderClass{
 border-style: solid; 
 border-color: black; 
 border-width: 2px; 
}

.someWidth{
 width: 200px; 
 height: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title> 'Merica! </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3x3 template.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
   <div id="container" class="boarderClass">
    <div id="header"class="boarderClass"> 
    </div>
    <div id="sectionOne" class="boarderClass someWidth" 
     <a href="Page 1.html">
      <img src="images/America.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
     </a>
    </div>
    <div id="sectionTwo" class="boarderClass someWidth imageLink" <a href="Page 2.html"><img src="images/Is.jpg" title="Is" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectionThree" class="boarderClass someWidth" <a href="Page 3.html"><img src="images/THE.jpg" title="THE" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectionFour" class="boarderClass someWidth" <a href="Page 4.html"><img src="images/Greatest.jpg" title="Greatest" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectionFive" class="boarderClass someWidth" <a href="Page 5.html"><img src="images/Country.jpg" title="Country" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectionSix" class="boarderClass someWidth" <a href="Page 6.html"><img src="images/In.jpg" title="In" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectionSeven" class="boarderClass someWidth"<a href="Page 7.html"><img src="images/THE.jpg" title="THE" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectionEight" class="boarderClass someWidth"<a href="Page 8.html"><img src="images/Entire.jpg" title="Entire" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectionNine" class="boarderClass someWidth"<a href="Page 9.html"><img src="images/World.jpg" title="World" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div id="footer"class="boarderClass">
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
 
 
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a single test link, something like: <a href="img.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200"/></a>

Comment: For the grouping, there are various ways to do it. One would be with bootstrap's <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">img stuff here</div> + 2 more col divs here </div>(closing of the row div), then repeat 2 more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing closing brackets (`>`) on almost *every* div in the HTML, as well as closing anchors (`</a>`)

```
<div id="sectionTwo" class="boarderClass someWidth imageLink"> <a href="Page 2.html"><img src="images/Is.jpg" title="Is" width="200" height="200" /></a></div>
```

Note the difference above... you'll need to fix this **multiple** times in your HTML.

Comment: When I close the tag is messes everything up and appears on my webpage....

<div> id="sectionTwo" class="boarderClass someWidth imageLink">

Comment: @RandyAllenGossard Close it in the **correct** spot -- `<div id="sectionTwo" class="boarderClass someWidth imageLink">` Look at what I posted again and compare.. character by character.

Answer (score 0):

Page 1.html is incorrect. Remove the space.  Eg. Page1.html

Also, you could use bootstrap and display the images using a modal instead of creating nine pages.

Comment: when I close the <div> tag my code de-activates and goes int "black text" that appears on my page

I closed all of my spaces in the file names. still same issues

Comment: He wants it to open up in the new window so i needed the target="_blank" in the href line of the relitive html file

Answer (score 0):

Ok first use page1.html or any other name without space and the second is your code 
you have typed like this

```
<div id="sectionTwo" class="boarderClass someWidth imageLink" <a href="Page 2.html"><img src="images/Is.jpg" title="Is" width="200" height="200" />
                </div>
```

Now take a look at your code, you forgot to add **>** in div, so your code will like this

```
<div id="sectionTwo" class="boarderClass someWidth imageLink"> <a href="Page 2.html"><img src="images/Is.jpg" title="Is" width="200" height="200" />
                </div>
```

Now,  will work well.

Comment: when I close the <div> tag my code de-activates and goes int "black text" that appears on my page